# Use declared variable in instance definition in Haskell

Tags: haskell, instance, variable-declaration

I'm trying to implement (a simplified version of) `Representable` for my data type, but I'm not allowed to use the first data type parameter in the definition:

```hs
question.hs
-----------

{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Representable f where
   type Rep f :: *
   tabulate :: (Rep f -> x) -> f x
   index    :: f x -> Rep f -> x

data F a b = F a b

instance Representable (F a) where
--                        ^
-- orfeas: It's right here, ghc!
  type Rep (F a) = a
  tabulate g = F a (g a)
  --             ^    ^
  -- ghc:        a not in scope :(
  index (F a b) = g where g a = b

main = return ()
```

How can I make ghc see `a` inside the `instance` implementation?

I expected the above to compile successfully, but I got this instead:

```bash
ghc -dynamic question.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( question.hs, question.o )

question.hs:15:18: error: Variable not in scope: a
   |
14 |   tabulate g = F a (g a)
   |                  ^

question.hs:15:23: error: Variable not in scope: a
   |
14 |   tabulate g = F a (g a)
   |                       ^
```

Comment: I see the answer already alluded to it, but I'm not sure you've followed, so: in `tabulate g = F a (g a)`, `F` takes values, not types, and `a` is a type.

Answer (score 2):

`a` is a type-level variable, but you're trying to use it in a value-level equation.

Let's call the type- and value-level constructors differently to make it clearer:

```
data FTL a b = FVL a b
```

Even clearer (but still the same thing) with annotations:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTSyntax, KindSignatures #-}

data FTL :: Type -> Type -> Type where
  FVL :: a -> b -> FTL a b
```

Let's also add some annotations in your proposed instance:

```
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs, UnicodeSyntax, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

instance ∀ (a :: Type) . Representable (FTL a) where
  type Rep (FTL a) = a
  tabulate :: (a -> x) -> F a x
  tabulate g = FVL (a :: Type??)
                   (g (a :: Type??) :: x)
```

It doesn't make sense to give something of type `Type` to a value-level constructor, nor to the function `g`. Instead, you should give *a value **of type** `a`* to them. But, well – you can't actually do that here, because you have no such value.

Really, the problem is that `F a` is **not** a representable functor.

Comment: Thanks! I think that there should be a way to make this representable though, as it's demanded (in a roundabout way) by ex. 6 of https://bartoszmilewski.com/2016/04/18/adjunctions/.

Comment: @orfeas pretty sure you're interpreting something wrong there, but this seems to be a good topic to ask another question about.

Comment: @orfeas AFAICS, in ex. 6  the product is a _left_ adjoint, the function is the _right_ one. You should able to let `data F a b = F (a->b)` (the right adjoint) and define `instance Representable (F a)`.